# How can I get Lightroom to export a list of filenames, from the colour-labeled (or flagged) pictures?

Tags: lightroom, filenames

Is there a way to just export a list of the filenames, instead of creating a copy of some of the photographs in a new folder? The list should be only those photographs that exist in a group (flagged/colour label/ etc.)

OS is Windows.

Comment: Check this out for details for mac and windows.  Was going to make an answer here, but searched first to see if it was out there... -->>
https://community.adobe.com/t5/lightroom-classic/how-to-export-a-list-of-selected-file-names-to-share-with-a-collaborator-or-client/m-p/7346741

Answer (score 5):

You can do this

1. Apply your filter in the library module,
2. Select all photos
3. Select "File Menu/Export as catalog..."
4. Click "Export selected photos only" (This doesnt export the photos, only the metadata) , uncheck the other checkboxes
5. Choose an appropriate filename for the .lrcat file, save it, (optionally use the .sqlite extension)
6. Open the .lrcat file in a database query tool that understands the sqlite data format, e.g. code: https://github.com/lazierthanthou/sqlite-manager
   , download: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/
7. Extract the filename info from table 'AgLibraryFile' with `SELECT basename , extension FROM AgLibraryFile` (customize the SQL),
8. save to csv file

(I admit it's a bit involved and awkward, but it gets the job done.)

**An even better solution is:**

1. Install [Jeffrey Friedl's Data Explorer Plugin](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/data-explorer).
2. Open this Plugin. (File/Plugin Extras/ jfDataExplorer Explore...)
3. Design a search using any criterion
4. Let the plugin search the catalog.
5. In the final dialog box, click "Save-to-tab-separated-values file" button

This way you can export even the weirdest and sophisticated searches. See screenshot attached.

[image: data-explorer dialog-box]

Answer (score 1):

I have the better way.

1. Move original file to another folder.
2. Select photos that you want to get the filenames of.
3. Menu **"Export with Preset"** -> **"For Email (Hard Drive)"**
4. Select Somefolder for Export
5. After Export you can see **"The file could not be found"**
6. click **"Save As..."** button and type Filename

Now you have a list of photo file names in a Text file.

***Remark:*** If you selected more than 1000 photos for Export, an error might occur.
please select only up to 1000 photos per time.

Comment: This answer could use a bit of clarification. In step 1 I guess the files need to be moved outside of Lightroom? Step 4: select the folder which includes the now missing files? Also you probably need to move the files back to their original folder in a step 7.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but a problem I've just run into. I need a list of all filenames for photos labeled "Green" in a set of folders.

You mentioned "instead of creating a copy of the photos in a new folder". Why not export to a temporary folder, capture the filenames, and then delete the copies of the photos?  The only downside is you'll need enough space to temporarily hold a copy of the photos, but this could be on an external drive or even a USB stick if you're really short on space. It's temporary.

For example,

1. Filter down to the photos for filenames you want to export using any set of criteria that you like.
2. Select all photos that you've filtered (Ctrl+A works well)
3. Click Export -> Copy Original File (or just about anything else)
4. Enter a new path, like "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\Export" that is empty.
5. When the export is finished, open Windows Explorer on the folder you created (if it doesn't automatically open).
6. Switch the "View" to "List".
7. Select all files (Ctrl+A makes this easy).
8. Right-click on any file and select "Copy as Path". On Windows 11 you might have to select "More options". If you don't see "Copy as Path", then hold down the shift key when you right click.
9. Open Notepad, NotePad++, or your favorite text editor.
10. Select "Paste" or press Ctrl+V.
11. Use Edit->Replace to remove the folder name and maybe quotes from the filenames, then save the list of files somewhere.
12. Delete the folder that contains the copies of your photos.

I find this is easier than the other suggestions above.